# Iterate an array with respect to another array's index in handlebars

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data, each

```
{{#each locationTable as |locationShifts index|}}
   {{#each get reasons index as |value|}}
     {{value}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I want to do something like this. Using 2 helpers at once "each" and "get". How can i achieve something like this?

Comment: What does `get` do?

Comment: get basically does similar to reasons[index] in a javascript file @76484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be

```
{{#each (get reasons index) as |value|}}
  {{value}}
{{/each}}
```

but I'm not 100% sure if `get` works for numeric indexes on arrays.

Comment: I am a 100% sure that get works for numeric indexes @Lux

Answer (score 3):

If I were approaching this problem in my own codebase, I would write an `@tracked` getter function in Octane or a computed property in pre-octane Ember that maps the two arrays into new objects. It's much nicer IMO to map them into objects that model the relation between them (rather than **rely** on each item's index in two separate arrays everywhere in your codebase which isn't something I'd find intuitive and something that seems likely to result in unexpected errors later on).

Let's say I have a list of names and a list of roles.

```
const names = ['Will', 'Wes', 'Janine'],
      roles = ['Father', 'Son', 'Mother'];

const people = names.map((name, idx) => {
  return {
    name: name,
    role: roles[idx]
  };
});
```

You can extrapolate how that might look as a computed/tracked property. The key is that I've managed to group the data logically. That way in a template you can just:

```
{{#each people as |person|}}
  {{person.name}} is a {{person.role}}
{{/each}}
```

rather than needing to walk to discrete arrays simultaneously. Model your data in javascript and the templates are easy to write/follow